# XML to Dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: python, xml, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to scrap an XML file and create a dataframe from tags on the XML file. I working on Databricks using pyspark.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <shorttitle>shorttitle_1</shorttitle>
  <shorttitle>shorttitle_2</shorttitle>
  <shorttitle>shorttitle_3</shorttitle>
  <shorttitle>shorttitle_4</shorttitle>
</note>
```

My code seems to scrap the the XML from the page and create a list from the tags but when I create my dataframe and try to input said list I only see a dataframe contain null values.

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


res = requests.get("http://files.fakeaddress.com/files01.xml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
short_title = soup.find_all('shorttitle')[0:2]

field = [StructField("Short_Title",StringType(), True)]

schema = StructType(field)

df = spark.createDataFrame(short_title, schema)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
|Short_Title|
+-----------+
|       null|
|       null|
+-----------+
```

Wanted Output:

```
+-------------+
|Short_Title  |
+-------------+
|shorttitle_1 |
|shorttitle_2 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: I think you can first create a dataframe on top of xml and then take xml schema using customSchema = df.schema and make use of the same in spark.createDataFrame(short_title, customSchema)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Spark-XML](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) package, which creates a Spark Dataframe directly from your XML file(s) without any further hassle.  It only becomes more complicated when you have nested keys in your XML file.

Installation of the package on your Databricks cluster is fairly straightforward using their maven repository, for which they provide the coordinates.  However, I am uncertain if the package is still being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Apache Spark XML processing using Databricks API, below is code sample 
snippet for same, for this first copy xml on hdfs or local.

```
schema = new StructType()
      .add("Short_Title",StringType)

df = spark.read
  .option("rowTag", "note")
  .schema(schema)
  .xml("files01.xml")

df.show()
```